# How to create custom transparent tabs at the bottom of an activity

Tags: java, android, tabs

I want to create three transparent tabs as [shown in the snapshot](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2wp7IN_lTtleGE3VTVhamp4MGc/view?usp=sharing) but don't know how to achieve it. i want it to be transparent such that users can see the listview behind it. I would welcome suggestions and sample reference or resources to enable implement this feature, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use `setAlpha()` method for making views transparent:

```
mView.setAlpha(0.5f); //that makes it 50% transparent
```

while `0f` if **full transparent**(not visible), and `1f` is **full opaque**(hasn't any transparency).

So, in your case use it with the layout of the tabs and/or the tabs itself.